# Não consigo sobrescrever uma variável em docker. Como resolver?

Tags: docker, sobrescrita

Tenho esse seguinte dockerfile:

```
...

ENV REMOTE_HOST abcd
RUN figlet SETTING__XDEBUG__php.ini
RUN { \
        echo '[xdebug]'; \
        echo 'zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_enable=1'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_port=9000'; \  
        echo 'xdebug.remote_autostart=1'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp'; \
        echo 'xdebug.idekey=dockerdebug'; \
        echo 'xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/var/www/html"'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_connect_back=0'; \
        echo 'xdebug.remote_host='${REMOTE_HOST}; \
    } >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

...
```

Como se observa, estou inciando o `xdebug.remote_host` com o valor teste **'abcd'**.

Levanto o container com o seguinte comando `docker run -e "REMOTE_HOST=123456" ...`

Depois que o container está funcionando, checo o conteúdo do php.ini é isso que tenho:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.idekey=dockerdebug
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/var/www/html"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_host=abcd
```

Ou seja, o xdebug.remote_host está sendo inicializado com o valor **abcd** passado no dockerfile, mas não consigo sobrescrever com o valor  **123456** passado no processo de levantamento do container segundo o que é sugerido na documentação [Overriding Dockerfile image defaults](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#overriding-dockerfile-image-defaults)     e    [Additionally, the operator can set any environment variable in the container by using one or more -e flags.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Possivelmente o seu comando **echo** esteja interpretando o valor da variável REMOTE_HOST.

**echo 'xdebug.remote_host='${REMOTE_HOST};**

Após criar a imagem, provavelmente, o php.ini deve estar ficando assim:
**xdebug.remote_host=abcd**

E você está querendo que ele fique assim:
**xdebug.remote_host=${REMOTE_HOST}**

Tente colocar a variável dentro das aspas simples ou tente fazer um escape do caracter especial **"$"** da variável  para que o resultado final seja como na linha acima:
**echo 'xdebug.remote_host=${REMOTE_HOST}';**